# Deleting duplicates in excel is too slow

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large worksheet with many duplicates. The duplicates are in column E and I have to delete the ones with the lowest number in column L. I'm using this code:

```
Sub Duplicados()

Dim i, lr

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("L2") _
    , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr - 1 To 1 Step -1

    If Cells(i, "E").Value = Cells(i + 1, "E") Then

            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

    End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

However it's too slow and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You should use a pivot-table to collate the entries, and then you can sort them by column L and delete the lowest ones.

Comment: change order to `Order1:=xlDescending` and use `Range(..).RemoveDuplicates` (not working in excel 2003)

Comment: check this link to do it manually http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx

Comment: I wrote `ActiveSheet.Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo` but it's only deleting the cells from the column and I need to delete the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

One reason your code takes so long is that it's deleting one row at a time. One thing you can do to speed up the process of your current structure would be to first identify all the rows that need to be deleted and then delete them all at once. See the following example for a way to do this using the [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method:

```
Dim rr As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("L2") _
, Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lr - 1 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "E") = Cells(i + 1, "E") Then
        If rr Is Nothing Then
            Set rr = Cells(i, 1)
        Else: Set rr = Union(rr, Cells(i, 1))
        End If
    End If
Next i

rr.EntireRow.Delete
```